# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio not showing top 200 rows to edit

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a data table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I would like to edit top 200 rows in my data table, when I select top 1000 rows I could see all my data(which is 13 rows) but when I click to edit top 200 rows I could only see 9 rows instead of 13.

Same thing happening with my other data tables I can't see my whole data to edit top 200 rows.

Is there anyone knows why this happened and what is the solution?

[image: This is what i see when i click edit top 200 rows]

[image: This is what i see when i click select top 1000 rows]

As you can see there are 5 rows difference between two.

Comment: What's the version of your SSMS?

Comment: SSMS version 18.6

Comment: When you have the edit window open, open the SQL Pane (CTRL-3) and show us an example of the SQL that's being generated.

Comment: I have tested this on your version and the previous one and it is working fine. Could to show the properties dialog of the SQL Pane?

Comment: That's the SQL being generated and shows 9 rows instead of 13: SELECT TOP (200) id, Date, Time, Devir, MotorKarti, MotorTipi
FROM   Parametreler

Comment: @trytobedeveloper There is no sense. Could export the data (it's only 9 rows) and add it to  your question?

Comment: @gotqn I added image description of the sample of my data sorry if it causes a 
misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit top 200 records

In Management studio - In Edit window - Select Pane-> Sql or Ctrl+3 then you can see n number of records

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqsfg.png

Comment: I have the Execute grayed out. Any idea why?